# How do I get the posts of a closed Facebook group using Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once("../src/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'APP_ID_HERE';
$config['secret'] = 'APP_SECRET_HERE';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$facebook->getAccessToken();
$patas_feed = $facebook->api('136304296439193/feed','GET');
var_dump($patas_feed);
?>
```

I'm using this code to get the wall feed of a closed Facebook group. Unfortunately, it returns nothing; however, if I were to use this with an open Facebook group, it works great and creates an array of everything. I think the problem is the access token. How do I make the access token accessible to closed groups?

P.S. I'm a member of the closed group, and I can always obtain admin access if ever.

Update:
I gave my account permission to the app. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to request the `user_groups` permission to access a closed group information.

> To read a Group, you need:
>
> - any valid `access_token` if the group is public (i.e. the group's privacy setting is `OPEN`)
> - `user_groups` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) for a user's non-public groups
> - `friends_groups` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) for a user's friend's non-public groups
> - Groups for Apps and Games require the use of an App `access_token`
>
> *Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/*